# Get the response of an other ajax call using ajaxcomplete in jquery

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I want to trigger another AJAx call response on an `ajaxcomplete` event. I need to call the response in a different section of the page. The other AJAX call is in the core functionality. So I am trying to write a custom `ajaxComplete` handler to handler the response:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(_event, _xhr, settings) {

console.log(settings.data)

}
```

Here is the JSON response of the other AJAX call that I get when there is a change to a drop-down value:

```
[
{
    "command": "insert",
    "method": "replaceWith",
    "selector": ".product--variation-field--variation_field_product_description__12345",
    "data": "This is description",
    "settings": null
}
]
```

console.log(settings.data)

Answer (score 0):

`.ajaxComplete` could work for your use-case, but you would have to add logic into the handler to determine if the response was for the specific request your are interested in and then parse data with `JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)`.

However, my preferred solution to this problem would be to use a [custom event](https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/). In the success handler of the core AJAX request, I would dispatch a custom action, like `$(document).trigger(MY_CUSTOM_EVENT, { response: response })`. I would then add a handler for this custom event in the other section that needs the response data: `$(document).on(MY_CUSTOM_EVENT, function (_event, data) { /* do something with data.response */ })`.

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/q62jvaz5/) with examples of both `.ajaxComplete` and the custom event.